# Get the column name along with the first row value?

Tags: mysql, database

how to get the column name along with the first row value in sql?

TABLE:

column1 | column2 | column3

---

row1     | row2     | row3

RESULT:

column1 row1

column2 row2

column3 row3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
'column1', column1, 'column2', column2, 'column3', column3
FROM
    sometable;
```